# Is female Wii Fit Trainer's hurtbox still smaller than the male's?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

In Smash 4, according to a friend who liked to play them, both female Wii Fit Trainer's model and [hurtbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/182355/222207) were smaller than her male counterpart's. This made it clearly advantageous to play the female version of the character.

However, the models look far closer in size in Ultimate. I haven't seen anyone at the professional level playing male Wii Fit (though I've seen several female Wii Fit's), but this may just be preference. Is there still a difference in their hurtboxes?

Comment: You'll need to provide a source for your assertion that the two costumes are different in SSB4, because I took a quick dive into the files and found nothing to suggest such.

Comment: @Toomai huh. My friend (who played Wii Fit in Smash 4) would always tell us this. If that's really the case, then "From [evidence] it looks like this wasn't a thing in Smash 4, so it's probably not a thing in Ultimate either" would be a perfectly good answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no competitive difference between the female and male Wii Fit Trainers in the Smash games - the differences are purely aesthetic. Their [Smash 4](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Wii_Fit_Trainer_(SSB4)) and [Ultimate](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Wii_Fit_Trainer_(SSBU)) Wiki pages list no differences - they would do so if there were differences. This also applies for the genders of Villager, Robin, Corrin, and Inkling, as well as the alternate costumes of Olimar/Alph and Bowser Jr/Koopalings.

Sakurai stated that any [changes between characters that are more than aesthetic and reflect different attributes warrant a separate character slot e.g. echo fighters.](https://www.siliconera.com/2014/07/15/sakurai-talks-difference-lucina-marth-smash-bros/) No difference in attributes = no separate character slot. For example the only attribute differences between Peach and Daisy in Smash Ultimate are [slightly different hurtboxes during certain animations](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Daisy_(SSBU)#Attributes).

EDIT: As per Toomai, it's not mechanically possible for different costumes to have different hit/hurtboxes. There is only one moveset file (which contains this data) per character. Lots of other stuff can be costume-specific, but not this.

Comment: I'll note here that it's not actually mechanically possible for different costumes to have different hit/hurtboxes, because there is only one moveset file (which contains this data) per character. A bunch of other stuff can be costume-specific, but not this.