# Do the different animations in the alternate costumes affect hurtboxes?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Some of the alternate costumes use different animations, like Inkling for example or, more recently, Byleth. Inkling's idle animation is different depending on if it's a female or male Inkling for example. Wouldn't that mean that their hurtboxes behave differently in their idle animation? Is there an actual theoretical/practical gameplay difference (however minor) between alternate costumes?

Because some people seem to have trouble seeing very obvious differences in animations, here's an example grabbed from Sakurai's Direct:

[image]

Notice how they hold their swords over their right shoulder. Let's say you had a Fox fire his Blaster from the left at the same height as their heads. If hurtboxes and hitboxes follow the animations (which is what I thought would be the case), wouldn't that mean that Fox would hit female Byleth in the head, while male Byleth's right hand would be hit?

Answer (score 1):

No, alternate costumes have never changed the hurtbox of any character. Hitboxes (and by extension, hurtboxes), are derived from the default skin. This is why characters like Male/Female Corrin & Robin share the same height, as they have the same hitbox and hurtbox on their attacks. This also applies to characters less "alternate costume" but more "echo fighter", like the Koopalings.

Comment: That makes no sense, I thought the hurt and hit boxes follow the animations? Why would they stay the same if the animations are different?

Comment: The animations are not different. Unless you care to provide a source for that claim.

Comment: ... really, dude? Did you even read my question? That was literally the entire point of my question, which your "answer" didn't even address: that animations are different, even if only slightly, for some alternate costumes, and I provided an example. And you want a source? What, do you want me to find a gif for you? I assume if you tried to answer a Smash Ultimate question, you probably have a copy of the game yourself, so why not boot it up and check it for yourself? You could go and check male and female Byleth, it's much easier to spot with them if you just look at their swords.

Comment: I booted up my copy of the game and found no differences in the animation. Instead of just saying you believe there's a difference, you should do your best to provide proof to support your claims.

Comment: Dude, LOOK AT MALE AND FEMALE BYLETH! Are you joking or what?

Comment: The models are separate from the hitbox models, if you didn't know that. A hitbox is a collision box that just covers the proportions of the body roughly. If alternate costumes actually changed hitboxes, then the competitive community would've picked up on it long ago. Currently none of the evidence seems to point in your favor..

Comment: If what you were saying was remotely true then Mii Fighter hitboxes would be based off their costumes, also implying that m/f Corrin and Robin also have different hitboxes

Comment: You seem to conflate different models with different animations here, which was never my point. My question was solely about different animations. In most fighting games (3d ones at least), the hurt and hitboxes follow the animations. If that is the case with Smash Ultimate, which I don't know if it is, then that would mean you have slight gameplay differences between the skins. Look at the example I added in the question, and tell me again how the animations aren't different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103982/discussion-between-senpai-and-noclue).

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with senpai, alternate costumes and associated different animations do not change the hurtboxes (and hitboxes) for the characters. However, I want to back this statement with a quote [from the Smash Wiki page](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Alternate_costume_(SSBU)).

> Pikachu, Pokémon Trainer, Villager, Wii Fit Trainer, Robin, Corrin,
>   Inkling, and Byleth all have male and female variants; and Olimar and
>   Bowser Jr. have model swaps that change them into different characters
>   with different names, complete with corresponding voice and Announcer
>   clips, though like all other alternate costumes, they bear no gameplay
>   differences.

And also [this previous Arqade answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/345825/219593), which states that it is mechanically impossible for alternate costumes to have different hurtboxes (and hitboxes).

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't that mean that their hurtboxes behave differently in their idle animation? Is there an actual theoretical/practical gameplay difference (however minor) between alternate costumes?

This is correct. Odd-costumed Byleth uses idle animations 1 and 2, while even-costumed Byleth uses idle animations 3 and 4, and they are sufficiently different that even though their hurtboxes are the same, there is a minor gameplay difference. (Note that they do use the same "base pose", so they both return to the same shape after executing other actions, before the idle animations start.)

Comment: Can you prove that those idle animations, different as they may, have different hurtboxes?

Comment: Animations do not "have" hurtboxes. Hurtboxes are a property of the character slot, and they always follow animations. This is one of the most fundamental axioms of the Smash Bros. engine. Unfortunately this is difficult to *prove* in this case, because the difference is so small that there are few (if any) hitboxes small and precise enough to hit Byleth 1's arm without hitting Byleth 2's arm or either's head.

Comment: Hurtboxes being a property of the character slot (which the two Blyeths share), and animations don't have hurtboxes, seems to suggest that the Blyeths have the same hurtboxes, not different.

Comment: Yes they have the same hurtboxes, which will always be in identical positions relative to the bones they're attached to. But if they use different animations, the hurtboxes will be accordingly located in different places relative to the global playing field, and thus cause a miniscule but nonzero gameplay difference.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8exYA7uNkLg seems to show that even with different animations, the hurtboxes are always located in the same place, shown in the case of female byleth having hitboxes disjointed from the actual arm movement.

Comment: I'm not sure what that video proves about *hurt*boxes. *Hit*boxes may or may not be attached to bones, and in any case only Byleth's *idle* animations differ, not the *attack* animatIons.