# How can I reliably place C4 on my enemies?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Snake's down special has him placing C4 on the ground that he can detonate by doing his down special again. I have seen it be placed on enemies before, and I have done it myself, but I can not do it consistently. Sometimes I will place it accidentally on an enemy while other times I will try to and not succeed.

The [wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Snake_(SSBU)#Special_Moves) says that you just need to be near to them to do it, but I feel that there is more to it, at least to doing it consistently.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've got bad news for you: you have to be **really** close to someone to be able to place C4 on them. How close, you ask? It looks like it actually depends on the opponent's [hurtbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/182355/222207)--meaning the smaller the character, the closer you'll have to be.

On the training stage with the opponent centered on 0, the furthest I could be was 7 "units"<sup>1</sup> for Pichu (one of the smallest in the game):

[image: Stuck Pichu]

but 12.5 "units" from Ridley (one of the largest):

[image: Stuck Ridley]

These distances also differ when Pichu/Ridley were facing the other way, making me think that this is indeed based on hurtbox size.

So your problem is likely that you're simply not close enough.

You could try to get in and find an opening where your opponent gives you enough time ([9 frames](http://kuroganehammer.com/Ultimate/Snake)) to plant the C4 on them, but then you're almost better off doing something like forward-tilt/up-tilt/grab which all come out faster or even forward-smash which is only 2 frames slower.

Instead, you can use the fact that **C4 will still be planted to the opponent even if they're shielding!**

So I'd say the most opportune time to use this would be after you've conditioned them to shield when you approach. This way, you can use whatever approach you've been, but mix up the attack for a run up sticky.

### Minor trivia I learned while experimenting

- Dropping a C4 from above will always make it stick to the floor. Even if you drop it directly over the opponent (much to my dismay--this was going to be my suggestion if it worked).
- If a character is "stuck" with the C4 and they pass another character, the C4 will transfer to the new character, even if this character is Snake himself! So be careful after you stick someone or when you detonate, you may be killing yourself! However, after a short window (I estimated about 20 frames), the C4 can be passed again. So even if it gets passed back onto you, you could try to stick it to the opponent again by getting close to them.
- The C4 will fall off of the character after a certain amount of time, so if it gets transferred back to you, don't fret. You'll just need to wait for it to fall off.
- Shielding can change the size of the opponent's hurtbox, so the "stick range" may change slightly if they're shielding--either way, I'd suggest playing safe and getting as close as you can.
- [Pichu puts her ears back when shielding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJAuN.jpg) to fit into the shield and it's the most adorable thing.

---

<sup>1. I'm calling each of the smallest squares a "unit" here.</sup>

Comment: Should also note that C4 will continually pass back and forth should the C4 end up sticking on you -- just brush up close to the enemy and it'll pass it back, like a game of tag.  So in a sense, you don't even have to manually detonate it, you can pass it back to the enemy, play a keepaway game, and let the 30 second timer autodetonate it for you for some extra mindgames.

Comment: @senpai ha! That sounds like a fun game! I added that it could be passed multiple times explicitly, good call.

Comment: Looks like the distance is 4 units from the left edge of a character's bounding box?

Comment: @Rogem maybe? It's difficult to say since the bounding boxes aren't really boxes in this game. All of this with the "units" is just to give a general idea of how close you need to be. For an actual distance, we'll need to wait for the dataminers to post their findings.

Answer (score 6):

Facts about the move:

- The C4 is 'stuck' on frame 9 to a fighter.
- sticking a C4 goes through shields,
  this cannot be parried (like a command grab, such Bowser's Flying
  Slam)
- range is very small as pointed out in the previous answer
  scohe001
- when the red light stops blinking, the c4 can be transferred to
  another. During the time the light blinks (about 2 seconds), it cannot be transferred
- the C4 explodes by itself after 1600 frames (roughly after 27
  seconds)

With this knowledge in mind:

- If they shield a lot, run up and stick them.
- Stages with platforms like Battlefield; an opponent above you shielding can still get a C4 stuck.
- As senpai pointed out, Snakes down throw forces a situation where the opponent has to getup, roll, or getup-attack. This is the only throw in the game that forces this (cannot be teched) and can set up a situation where you can stick the opponent if you read correctly.
- Also worth noting is that damage scales the amount of frame advantage Snake has with down throw. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQD7zaWSLV8) for more information on that. You can use those extra frames of advantage to read where your opponent goes and stick C4 on them.

As a side note, if you've stuck your opponent with C4 or if you are about to transfer C4 on them, a 100% true KO confirm is Back-throw -> C4 detonation.

I have noticed from personal experience (not confirmed) that a stuck C4 can fall off after being hit with a strong move, and it tends to happen more when the damage % on the stuck fighter is lower.

Comment: +1 for the red light blinking, I didn't even notice that. Do you have any frame data on when that happens by chance?

Comment: Thanks, and I don't have frame data for how long it blinks for. I know that it begins blinking as soon as the C4 is planted or stuck (if you do it in the air, it begins to blink as soon as it falls and sticks to the ground). I know it's about 2 seconds that it blinks, so it is roughly 120 frames give or take.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to stick C4 on an enemy is after performing a down grab -- aka, Snake's sleeper hold.  This works more reliably at high percentages as the down throw "stunlock" animation plays out a little longer and opponents have to mash harder to get out.

Comment: It might be worth noting that at the percent where this is possible, it might be a better option to use up-tilt, which will come out 3 frames faster and likely kill at that percent. Still a nice think-outside-the-box option though!

Comment: for reference, at 160% dthrow > utilt is guaranteed on all characters

Answer (score 2):

One of the best setups to stick someone is to condition them to shield on a platform and stick them through the shield.
Whenever they land on a platform above you, hit them immediately with an aerial, probably Bair or Nair.  Once they start shielding this consistently, you can jump directly into them and stick them through the shield (stick does go through shields).  You'll want to be overlapping their character as much as possible since the stick hitbox is pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combo I found on Smashboards. It guarantees a stick with your c4 on any enemy (I've tested it). It's a little tricky though. It works from 10-20% and kills above 13%. You need to down air and hit all 4 with just enough momentum to reach wherever they land (If the tech it doesn't work), jab lock them, and plant the sticky. To kill you need to either read them and land an up smash or pull out the mortar fast enough to hit them with the base before they get up, and then detonate at the peak of their launch arc. (you need to move slightly forward after the jab lock to hit the up smash)