# Why does Link take so little damage from a Bomb Impact Launch (windbomb)

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have recently learned how to BIL (windbomb), but was wondering why even when you fail you take so little damage.

Here's what I've picked up:

Success: ½ - ¾ ❤︎

Fail: 2 - 3 ½ ❤︎

While a normal bomb, from what I remember, is closer to 4 - 5 ❤︎.

Why is exploding in a BIL so relatively harmless compared to normal explosions? Does it have to deal with Bullet Time like so many other glitches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is collision damage, not explosion damage.

Bombs in BotW don't actually blow each other up, they knock them away, because bombs aren't "breakable", like crates and boxes. This also explains why mobs can kick them, or why you can knock them around, without them blowing up.

The windbomb technique doesn't hit Link with the explosion, it hits him with the second bomb, that gets launched by the explosion wave of the first. The reason Link doesn't get hit by the explosion is because the physics of hitting Link with the second bomb sends him flying faster than it does for the blast wave to hit him.

This also explains the difference between the damage of a successful and unsuccessful launch - they hit Link’s hurtbox differently, causing a different "impact" between the [bombs’ hitbox, and Link’s hurtbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182350/what-do-hitbox-and-hurtbox-mean).

Comment: They do, actually. Try it: drop two bombs next to each other and detonate one. The other one detonates too. The idea of a windbomb is that the bombs are positioned such that they don't detonate each other and instead knock themselves into Link.